# Spring Integration HTTP outbound gateway retry based on reply content

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I'm using an API that works in 2 steps:

1. It starts processing of a document in async way where it provides you an id that you use for step 2
2. It provides an endpoint where you can get the results but only when they are ready. So basically it will always give you a 200 response with some details like the status of the processing.

So the question is how can I implement a custom "success" criteria for the HTTP outbound gateway. I would also like to combine it with a RetryAdvice which I already have implemented.

I've tried the following but first of all the message's payload that is provided in the HandleMessageAdvice is empty, and secondly the retry is not triggered:

```
.handle(Http.outboundGateway("https://northeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3" +
        ".0/read/analyzeResults/abc")
        .mappedRequestHeaders("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key")
        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET), c -> c.advice(this.advices.retryAdvice())
              .handleMessageAdvice(new AbstractHandleMessageAdvice() {
    @Override
    protected Object doInvoke(MethodInvocation invocation, Message<?> message) throws Throwable {
        String body = (String) message.getPayload();
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(body))
            throw new RuntimeException("Still analyzing");
        JSONObject document = new JSONObject(body);
        if (document.has("analyzeResult"))
            return message;
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("Still analyzing");
    }
}))
```

I've found this answer from Artem from 4 years back but first of all I didn't find the reply channel method on the outbound gateway and secondly not sure if this scenario has already been improved in the newer version of Spring Integaration: [http outbound retry with conditions (For checker condition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538019/http-outbound-retry-with-conditions-for-checker-condition).

**UPDATE**

Following Artem's suggestion I have the following:

```
.handle(Http.outboundGateway("https://northeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3" +
        ".0/read/analyzeResults/abc")
        .mappedRequestHeaders("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key")
        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET), c -> c.advice(advices.verifyReplySuccess())
        .advice(advices.retryUntilRequestCompleteAdvice()))
```

And the advice:

```
@Bean
public Advice verifyReplySuccess() {
    return new AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) {
            try {
                Object payload = ((MessageBuilder) callback.execute()).build().getPayload();
                String body = (String) ((ResponseEntity) payload).getBody();
                JSONObject document = new JSONObject(body);
                if (document.has("analyzeResult"))
                    return message;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Still analyzing");
        }
    };
}
```

But now when I debug the *doInvoke* method, the body of the payload is **null**. It's strange as when I execute the same GET request using Postman, the body is correctly returned. Any idea?

The body from response using Postman looks like this:

```
{
    "status": "succeeded",
    "createdDateTime": "2020-09-01T10:55:52Z",
    "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2020-09-01T10:55:57Z",
    "analyzeResult": {
        "version": "3.0.0",
        "readResults": [
            {
                "page": 1,........
```

Here is the payload that I get from the outbound gateway using callback:

[image]

```
<200,[Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", Content-Type:"application/json; charset=utf-8", x-envoy-upstream-service-time:"27", CSP-Billing-Usage:"CognitiveServices.ComputerVision.Transaction=1", apim-request-id:"a503c72f-deae-4299-9e32-625d831cfd91", Strict-Transport-Security:"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload", x-content-type-options:"nosniff", Date:"Tue, 01 Sep 2020 19:48:36 GMT"]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no `request` and `reply` channel options in Java DSL because you simply wrap that `handle()` into `channel()` configuration or just chain endpoints in the flow natural way and they are going to exchange messages using implicit direct channels in between. You can look into Java DSL `IntegrationFlow` as a `<chain>` in the XML configuration.

Your advice configuration is a bit wrong: you need declare your custom advice as a first in a chain, so when exception is thrown from there a retry one is going to handle it.

You should also consider to implement an `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice` to align it with the `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` logic.

You implement there a `doInvoke()`, call `ExecutionCallback.execute()` and analyze the result to return as is or throw a desired exception. A result of that call for `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` is going to be an `AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder` and probably a `ResponseEntity` as a `payload` to check for your further logic.

Comment: Thanks Artem. Please take a look at my UPDATE.

Comment: What you show there is not a ` body` of the `ResponseEntity`. All those are just HTTP headers and status `200 OK`. No body in that HTTP response as far as I see.

Comment: That's a copy of the whole payload from the IntelliJ debugger. It doesn't show the body as it's null. I could post an image if needed...

Comment: What does body have to be then? I thought null means you still have to retry...

Comment: Please take a look at the UPDATE again, I added the postman response.
Can it be that it has something to do with the Transfer-Encoding:"chunked"? Maybe by using callback it's not properly "chunked" and the remaining chunks are not requested?

Comment: Hi Artem, any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how that is possible because the further logic in the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` is really based on the `getBody()` from the `ResponseEntity`. Can you try with the `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` for that `Http.outboundGateway()` instead of default one?

Comment: You mean like this: .requestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()) ?
Unfortunately the body is still null... Any other idea?

Comment: So I'm just re-implementing it using simple handle with restTemplate and I'm still getting empty body as response so it definitely has nothing to do with the outbound gateway I guess...

Comment: Consult with your service provider what could be a reason for such an empty body from them.

Comment: Ok I just figured it out... I was using restTemplate with ResponseEntity<JSONDocument> instead of ResponseEntity<String>. Now it works with restTemplate. Unfortunately the problem with outbound gateway is still unresolved :/

Comment: Why don’t you make an expected response type as that String, too?

Comment: Ok this was almost solved  I thought I tested it properly but I guess not really... The problem that I have now is that when the RuntimeException("Still analyzing") is thrown, the retry is not happening. Shall I be doing something different than throwing an Exception?

Comment: I guess you talk about your answer. The problem that those advices are wrapped to each other into a chain. So, the next advice is called withing the previous. Therefore to make your retry advice working after an exception from another one, that `advices.retryUntilRequestCompleteAdvice()` should be definitely first in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Following Artem's suggestion I came up with the following (additional trick was to set the *expectedResponseType* to String as otherwise using the *ResponseEntity* the body was empty):

```
.handle(Http.outboundGateway("https://northeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3" +
        ".0/read/analyzeResults/abc")
        .mappedRequestHeaders("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key")
        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET).expectedResponseType(String.class),
        c -> c.advice(advices.retryUntilRequestCompleteAdvice())
              .advice(advices.verifyReplySuccess()))
```

And the advice:

```
@Bean
public Advice verifyReplySuccess() {
    return new AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) {
            Object payload = ((MessageBuilder) callback.execute()).build().getPayload();
            if (((String) payload).contains("analyzeResult"))
                return payload;
            else
                throw new RuntimeException("Still analyzing");
        }
    };
}
```